# Books on machine learning and condensed matter?

Tags: density-functional-theory, reference-request, machine-learning, many-body-physics

What are the best books on the use of machine learning in condensed matter, focusing on density functional theory and many-body physics?

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future! By searching "Machine learning DFT" I found [this](https://dmol.pub/) & [this](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Development_of_Machine_Learning_Algorith.html?id=hd5FAQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y). What have you found so far? I think "**machine learning** for **condensed matter**, focused on **DFT** and **many-body physics**" is an extremely strict combination of four different things. You're more likely to find review papers than books. Why does it need to be a book?

Comment: @NikeDattani You are right. I have not found specific books focusing on these topics. This [review article](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/23746149.2020.1797528) mentioned some of them, but they are not really what I need.

Comment: What do you **need**? Why is a review article not good enough?

Comment: The review article is really good, but I need more comprehensive books.

Comment: We are talking about a very new area which is extensively covered by reviews. How a book is better in that? Are you looking for an intro level textbook?

Comment: @Bekaso if you're not going to answer our questions, and won't say why a "comprehensive book" is needed, rather than a review article, then the question would get closed since the asker doesn't seem interested.